# How do I check if PostGIS is installed in my PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, postgis

I'm trying to check whether or not the PostGIS extension is installed, as a PG query. I'm unable to find this info out.

Answer (score 2):

In psql CLI use `\dx`  to display all installed extensions in the current database or with SQL:

```
select * from pg_extension
```